# When the lines of a file or directory get too long, upgrade to ls list format? 

Tags: bash, bashrc, coreutils

Is there a way I can do this? For example if a gets a long name like:

```
i-have-names-that-are-too-long-to-describe/
i-have-names-that-are-too-long-to-describe-2/
i-have-names-that-are-too-long-to-descri-3/
```

Can I "upgrade" over from `ls` to `ls -l` given that I have a name of a file or directory that is longer than than say, 20 characters?

Is there a way to set up a bash function in my `.bashrc` to do this?  I'll call the resulting function lls().

**@tripleee asked:**

> Do you want `ls -l` when the input file name is long? Why? It will make the output longer, not shorter. What if you receive a mix of long and short filenames?

I want it more so that reading the long filenames are systematized to a list (and easier for me to digest and read going down a fixed column); for a mix of long and short filenames, I would default to the list format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no builtin option in `ls` that does what you want. You'd have to parse the output then restart if "long" filenames are found, or do something like:

```
$ ls ??????????* >& /dev/null && ls -l || ls
```

(Put as many `?` as your length limit. You can set that up as an alias.)

Why don't you simply use `ls -1`? (That's a one, not a lowercase L.) It always lists files in a single column. (Or pipe `ls` to `more` or `less`, which also goes to single column display.) Or use `find` with `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: I did not know about `ls -1`, thanks! Also, great answer, that's a neat way of going about doing what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ $(ls "$@" | ( max=0; while read l ; do len=${#l} ; [[ $max -lt $len ]] && max=$len; done; echo $max )) -gt 20 ]
then
    ls "$@"
else
    ls -l "$@"
fi
```

or, thanks to manatwork suggestion, this much simpler way which assumes GNU wc is available:

```
[[ $(ls "$@" | wc -L) -gt 20 ]] && ls "$@" || ls -l "$@"
```

Comment: While assuming GNU tools, would not be easier using `wc`'s `-L` or `--max-line-length` switch?

Comment: Even if `wc`'s `-L` switch is not available, using `wc` for counting is still shorter and faster: `ls | tr -c 'a\n' 'a' | sort -r | head -1 | wc -m`. But there is a small inconvenience: this will output actual max length+1.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for the comments, reply updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my independent attempt of what I wanted:

```
lls(){
  opt="   "      
  for i in $(ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f9)  
  do   
    count=$(echo $i | wc -m)  
     if [ $count -gt 20 ] ; then    
       opt=" -l"; break;           
     fi    
  done  
  ls $opt
}
```

I placed this in my .bashrc.  This does require the use of tr, cut, and wc though.